# Reassigning variable in loop, Scala Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, twirl

I have a problem with reassigning variables..

```
@myVar = {<a href="uno">Uno</a>}
@for (item <- LOOP ) {
    @myVar = {<a href="@item.url">@item.value</a>} //This part is not reassigning the varbiable but only displaying it + the new value
}
```

Comment: Such mutable code can be unsafe, and is useless

Comment: Play templates don't support re-assignment. Why do you need that? Most likely there's a better approach.

Comment: I managed to work around this... Thanks for the replies.